# How to choose an image from the gallery or the camera when I am in fragment using Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

When I press the button, I call this function

It is a Dialog to choose between the camera or the gallery

```
binding.ProfileChangeImage.setOnClickListener {
            showPictureDialog()
    }

private fun showPictureDialog() {
        val pictureDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action")
        val pictureDialogItems = arrayOf("Select photo from gallery", "Capture photo from camera")
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems
        ) { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> choosePhotoFromGallary()
                1 -> takePhotoFromCamera()
            }
        }
        pictureDialog.show()
    }
```

I used this code to open the camera or gallery

```
private fun choosePhotoFromGallary() {
            val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
        }

private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA)
    }
```

[But as you can see dear the startActivityForResult function is deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODQfW.png)

and finally, this is a fun onActiviyResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data: Intent?) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                val contentURI = data.data
                try {
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context?.contentResolver, contentURI)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    binding.profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
                catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            val thumbnail = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            binding.profileImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

but I used this code in UI, I want to implement this with MVVM.